# EAR classloader doesn't see ApplicationInsights.xml located in jar

Tags: java, azure, gradle, jar, ear

I have the following problem: I try to deploy the Azure telemetry configuration in jar file that is located in the war file inside main ear. Unfortunately, during server startup some errors occur as ApplicationInsights.xml cannot be found. I debugged it and I found out that it cannot be read by com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.config.ConfigurationFileLocator.getConfigurationFile().

There is a structure of my module:

```
azure
|_ src
   |_ main
         |_ java
         |     |_ mypackage
         |                |_ MicrometerRegistryConfigurationListener.java
         |_ resources
                    |_ ApplicationInsights.xml
```

There is MicrometerRegistryConfigurationListener.java:

```
@WebListener
public class MicrometerRegistryConfigurationListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        MeterRegistry azureMeterRegistry = new AzureMonitorMeterRegistry(new AzureMonitorConfig() {
            @Override
            public String get(String key) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Duration step() {
                return Duration.ofSeconds(5);
            }
        }, Clock.SYSTEM);

        new JvmThreadMetrics().bindTo(azureMeterRegistry);
        new JvmMemoryMetrics().bindTo(azureMeterRegistry);
        new JvmGcMetrics().bindTo(azureMeterRegistry);

        servletContextEvent.getServletContext().setAttribute("AzureMonitorMeterRegistry", azureMeterRegistry);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

    }
}
```

And there is a structure of ear:

```
ear
  |_ war
       |_ WEB-INF/lib
                    |_ azure.jar
                               |_ ApplicationInsights.xml
```

Of course, azure.jar contains also classes, i.a. MicrometerRegistryConfigurationListener.

What is going on? Why ApplicationInsights.xml is not visible?

Comment: It needs to be read as an InputStream as a CLASSPATH resource.  Either that's not being done properly OR the classpath isn't set properly.

Comment: How to set the classpath?

Comment: I think it would be in META-INF

Answer (score 0):

Cause jar is a file, it's not a folder. The loader tries to access a file system path, but it can not access a path in your JAR. So you could use the `resource.getInputStream()` method to retrieve it as a InputStream. You could get details from this doc:[Java: Load file from classpath in Spring Boot](https://smarterco.de/java-load-file-from-classpath-in-spring-boot/).

Example code:

```
public class EnvResolver {
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
public EnvResolver(){
    resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
}
public List GetEnvConfig() throws IOException {
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:test-environment.yml");
    System.out.println("FileName: " + resource.getFilename());
    InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();
    Map<String, Map<String, String>> result = yaml.load(inputStream);
    List<TestEnvVo> envList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String key : result.keySet()) {
        TestEnvVo testEnvVo = new TestEnvVo();
        testEnvVo.setEnvName(result.get(key).get("name"));
        testEnvVo.setDomain(result.get(key).get("domain"));
        envList.add(testEnvVo);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    return envList;
}
}
```

After searching, I found another way to configure it, in your POM file add the `resources` configuration. You could have a try.

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resource</directory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
            <include>**/*.xml</include>
            <include>**/*.tld</include>
        </includes>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Hope this could help you.

**UPDATE:**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream resourceInputStream = null;
        URL resourceURL = Hello.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/hello.json");
        if(resourceURL == null) {
            System.out.println("Get the InputStream of file in IDE");
            resourceInputStream = new FileInputStream(Hello.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()+"../../src/main/resources/hello.json");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Get the InputStream of file from runnable jar");
            resourceInputStream = Hello.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/hello.json");
        }
        System.out.println();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceInputStream));
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line+"\n");
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
    }
```

Comment: But I use gradle. How would it look like in gradle?

Comment: @wojtek1902, you could use classLoader getResource method to read file, I update the example code. And maybe you could try to edit the POM file the way I posted.

Comment: But I use gradle, I don't have POM file. And the file is loaded in the following way:

Comment: @wojtek1902,you could add something in build.gradle to generate the pom file:

Comment: apply plugin: 'maven'

task writeNewPom << {
    pom {
        project {
            inceptionYear '2018'
            licenses {
                license {
                    name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                    url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    distribution 'repo'
                }
            }
        }
    }.writeTo("pom.xml")
}

Comment: @wojtek1902, or you could continue to use the classLoader.